# how php and javascript communicate specifically with this code

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to write a php and javascript code that's going to behave similarly to the code I have below (I didn't write the code) but I'm a little confused on what's going on in the php and how the two are communicating. I've tried to watch videos and read about php but I'm still pretty confused by it.
Then the javascript makes requests to the php when its buttons are clicked and the php sends information back.

The general function of the php file is it displays the contents of a random file in the http://webster.cs.washington.edu/cse154/services/flashcards/pokemon directory. It can take in a parameter called mode. When the user passes in a mode value of categories it outputs a list of all of the folder names in http://webster.cs.washington.edu/cse154/services/flashcards. Otherwise, it just displays the contents of a random file as before.

I get it on a broad overview but I'm still kind of confused on how the php code is working. Like I said I'm trying to write a code that's going to be quite similar to this so I just am trying to get a better understanding of how php works but all the information i've read hasn't been that helpful.

```
<?php
# Solution to CSE 154 Flashcard lab.
# generates a JSON list of categories if passed a parameter mode
# with the value of categories. Otherwise outputs a random question
# from the passed in category in XML.

$mode = $_GET["mode"];
$category = $_GET["category"];
$url = "../../cse154/services/flashcards/";

if($mode == "categories") {
    outputJson($url);

} else {
    outputXml($url, $category);
}

# outputs the list of available categories in JSON
function outputJson($url) {
    $files = glob($url . "*");
    $json = array("categories" => array());
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $count = count(glob($file."/*"));
        $json["categories"][basename($file)] = $count;
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    print(json_encode($json));
}

# outputs a random question about the provided category in XML
function outputXml($url, $category) {
    $files = glob($url . "$category/*");
    $index = array_rand($files);
    // this is a great place to use list!!
    list($ques, $ans) = file($files[$index]);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $card = $dom->createElement("card");
    $dom->appendChild($card);
    $question = $dom->createElement("question");
    $question->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($ques));
    $card->appendChild($question);
    $answer = $dom->createElement("answer");
    $answer->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($ans));
    $card->appendChild($answer);

    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    print($dom->saveXML());
}

?>


/* javascript */
(function() {
var category = "computerscience";
var xml = null;

// sets up onclick handlers
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("viewAll").onclick = viewAll;
    document.getElementById("next").onclick = next;
};

// sends an ajax request to the passed in address.
// calls the passed in function when the request returns.
function ajax($adress, $function) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = $function;
    request.open("GET", $adress, true);
    request.send(); 
}

// makes a request for all of the categories.
function viewAll() {
    ajax("flashcards.php?mode=categories", displayAll); 
}

// displays all categories in a list on the page. 
function displayAll() {
    $json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    for($cat in $json.categories) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = $cat; 
        li.onclick = choose;
        document.getElementById("categories").appendChild(li);
    } 
}

// sets a new category as the category all questions should come from. 
function choose() {
    category = this.innerHTML;
}

// displays the next question if it was last displaying an answer or nothing. 
// displays the answer to the previous question otherwise. 
function next() {
    if(!xml) {
        ajax("flashcards.php?category=" + category, displayNext);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = xml.querySelector("answer").textContent;
        xml = null;
    }
}

// displays the question that it recieved from the server.
function displayNext() {
    xml = this.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = xml.querySelector("question").textContent;
}
})();
```

Comment: This is **super broad**.  Tell us what you do understand, or don't understand, and ask a specific question or two.  But "how does all this code work" could take a small book to answer.

Comment: Sorry I know that was kind of generic. Let me just explain how I want to emulate this code to write what I want to do. https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16sp/homework/6/spec.pdf this is what I'm working on but I'm very lost on how the php retrieves information from the folder on the server. So I guess I'm mainly confused on how the php in the code above gets the information from the webpage and sends it to the javascript. Because if I could just figure out how to actually start getting that information I could figure this out.

Comment: like in https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16sp/homework/6/spec.pdf I have to retrieve files and folders that are on a server with my php and create json and xmls with it then have a javascript that is going to grab the information from the json and xmls and put it in an http but I'm just kind of lost on the first step of how a php grabs information from the files on the server